# Any way to automate desktop GUI using Python just like automating web forms with JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, python, user-interface, webautomation

As we all know, filling out the web forms automatically is possible using JavaScript. Basically, We find the ID of related element using Inspect (Ctrl + I) in i.e Chrome and write a javascript code in the chrome console to automate what we want to do by code.

Just like that, is it possible to automate desktop apps using python? if yes how ?

Comment: Could you use something like PyAutoGui which automates mouse and keyboard movements on the entire screen. It would have to be pretty hardcoded but should work: https://pyautogui.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

Comment: Thank you for your answer, that would work and actually I was gonna look at it too. However, I am not sure if I can extract data from the application by using this. I dont think PyAutoGui allows to read data from GUI. Am I wrong ?

Comment: I don't think it would. A really obtuse way to do so would be to screenshot your window when needed, which can be automated, then process that image using an ocr library like pytesseract. From there, you would be able to access the text. I wouldn't imagine this solution to be good, however.

Comment: Yeah, I would like to make something robust and reliable and it seems it is not. But, this would be the solution for the worst scenerio. Thank you for your time and help!

Answer (score 1):

You can do this in python using **selenium**. Selenium is an open-source testing tool, used for functional testing and also compatible with non-functional testing.
You can refer to this [link](https://www.guru99.com/selenium-python.html) to get started.

Comment: I think it's not what OP want.

Comment: In the link you shared, it is for web automation which I used to work with. Is there any way to use Selenium as desktop app automation?

Comment: what kind of desktop are you asking?

Comment: the desktop application which has GUI and which I did not coded by myself. We can give an example as photoshop, outlook etc.

Answer (score 0):

[Pywinauto](https://pywinauto.github.io/)  is a GUI automation library written in pure Python and well developed for Windows GUI.